# Simple Ruby on Rails Controller error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my website I am trying to enter Employee's last name so that it shows me the corresponding phones that Employee has sold. So in terminal I typed this in

```
rails g controller showemployeesales employeenamein salesout
```

I edited my controller, route.rb, input, and outputfiles. Here is my code for those sections:

Controller: `

```
         class ShowemployeesalesController < ApplicationController
         def employeenamein
         end

         def salesout
         @employee_name = params[:employee_name_in]
         @r = Employee.find_by_last(@employee_name)
         @sale_list = @r ? @r.sales : nil
         @sale_list = Sale.all
         end
         end
```

Input File:

```
  <h2>Please enter the name of the Employee for whom you want to show 
  sales</h2>

  <%= form_tag(showemployeesales_salesout_path, :controller 
  "showemployeesales", :action => "salesout", :method => "post")

<div class="field">
<%= label_tag :Employee_Name %><br />
<%= text_field_tag :employee_name_in %>
</div>

<div class="action">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Employee Name" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Output File:

```
  <center><h1>These are the sales for <%= @employee_name %></h1></center>

  <center><table width = 65% border = 1>
  <tr> <th> Phone Name </th><th> Phone ID Number </th>
   <% @sale_list.each do |m| %>


   <tr> <td> <%= m.mobile %> </td> <td> <%= m.employee %></td></tr>

    <% end %> </table> </center>
```

After I run my website I get an error message saying:

```
  `undefined method `find_by_last' for #<Class:0x007f9d1e963170> Did you mean? 
   find_by_sql
```

Also when I navigate to my "/showemployeesales/employeenamein"

I get an error saying:`/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')' ...es_salesout_path, :controller "showemployeesales", :action =... ... ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...controller "showemployeesales", :action => "salesout", :meth... ... ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...esales", :action => "salesout", :method => "post") ... ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting keyword_end <div class="field"> ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected '<' <%= label_tag :Employee_Name );@output_buffer.safe_append='<br /> ^ /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/showemployeesales/employeenamein.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

And it highlights this line `<%= form_tag(showemployeesales_salesout_path, :controller "showemployeesales", :action => "salesout", :method => "post")`

Answer (score 1):

Query the record like: `Model.where(email: 'example@domain.com').last`

Comment: `find_by` only returns one instance, can't apply `last` to it

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. I'm fairly new at Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I originally used `Model.find_by` which returns an individual record so you can't use `.last` which applies to a collection/array.